# How to output a list of links from the following code

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to output a series of links I've scraped from a website. The html is in a pretty standard hierarchy: div, h4, a, href.

Using Python and BeautifulSoup I've pulled the list out using the following script:

```
for record in soup.findAll('div',{"class":"title"}):
    print(record)
```

which outputs the following info as a repeating series:

```
<div class="title">
<h4>
<a href="[the link]" id="[the id]" target="" title="[the title]">[the text]</a>
</h4>
```

So far, so good.

I then want to pull out the links alone. For some reason I can't separate them from the surrounding text.

I've tried the following script:

```
print(record.href) #outputs "None"
print(record.findAll('a',{"href"})) #outputs "[]"
print(record.findAll('h4',{"a":"href"})) #outputs "[]"
```

Any pointers as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: href is not a tag, its a property. Simply seach all `a` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `findAll` again and then access the href value via `["href"]`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="title">
<h4>
<a href="[the link]" id="[the id]" target="" title="[the title]">[the text]</a>
</h4>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for record in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "title"}):
    print(record.findAll("a")[0]["href"])
```

Which prints:

```
[the link]
```

If there is more than one `<a>` inside the `<div>`, you can use a loop again, of course.